# Bootstrap hide/show password button cant show up

Tags: bootstrap-4, passwords

Im making a website woth bootstrap right now and I downloaded the darkly theme from bootswatch.com. I'm trying to make a show/hide password button inside of the password input field. Turns out, the bootswatch theme doesnt have the nessecary files for the little eye button to show up. Does anyone know how I can get these files so that I can keep my theme. Thanks